# c# HtmlGenericControl not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlcontrols

I've got a aspx page that dynamically renders social media sharing links.

The code looks something like this.

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl newDiv =      
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");

newDiv.ID = "customFB1";
newDiv.InnerHtml = "<div class='fb-share-button' data-href='http://www.website.com/folder/"+custNumber+".html' data-layout='button_count' data-mobile-iframe='true'><a class='fb-xfbml-parse-ignore' target='_blank' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.website.com/folder/"+custNumber+".html&amp;src=sdkpreparse'>Share</a></div>";
customFB.Controls.Add(newDiv);
```

Now the source works perfectly.  Unfortunately 80% of the time when the page loads I have to hit F5 (hard refresh) to actually render the html.  When I expect the source when its not render, its there, but won't display.

Any thoughts on how I can get the control to render without hitting F5.  My customers won't know to hit F5 hah.

Thanks,

Comment: Tested it and it works as expected. When and where are you adding `newDiv`?

Comment: On the aspx page.   The above source is in the aspx.cs page.  

<div id="customFB" runat="server"></div>

fyi.  I get to this page via a javascript window.open call

Comment: Ohh and all the source is in the onLoad page event

Comment: btw i know the source works..its about the rendering of the controls

Comment: Fixed it.   What I had to do was pass a time parameter in the url to remove caching.   Worked like a champ.  Issue was with window.open and not any of the C# code